# Burial Traditions

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, geography

<sub>This is part 56 of the puzzle series [Around the World in Many Days](/q/118900/41973). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling,

The answers to these twelve rebuses are single words in alphabetical order. Your job is to solve them and group the answers to form four clues, each in turn giving a one-word answer.

Today I have visited a town built on steep hills to learn about traditional burial customs. Can you guess where I am?

Love, Gladys.

[image: Rebus images]

<sub>**Image credits**:

#1 left: TUBS, CC BY-SA 3.0

#1 bottom right: Пресс-служба Президента РФ, CC BY 4.0

#4: Pernod Ricard, CC BY-SA 3.0

#8: TUBS, CC BY-SA 3.0

#9: Donald McKague, CC BY 2.0

#10: Angela George, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

---

Gladys will return in *[Riverboat Soufflé](/q/126052/41973)*.

Comment: Am I missing something, or should R2C1 read "40-0" instead of "45-0"?

Comment: @user2390246 Augh, you're absolutely right. How did I manage to get get that wrong?

Comment: Fixed now. That's embarrassing lol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gladys is visiting:

> **[SAGADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagada)** in the Philippines.

First solve the 12 rebuses, like so:

> *Row 1:*
>  COMPUTING = CO for Colorado + MG containing PUTIN
>  COUNTY = UN in COT(Y)
>  HARBOR = date of PEARL HARBOR attack, minus PEARL
>  JACOB'S = JACOB’S Creek (wine brand)
>
>  *Row 2:*
>  LOVELACE = LOVE (0 in tennis) + L (litre) + ACE
>  MILITARY = ILIT in MARY
>  OFFICER = OFF + RICE with the R moved to the other end
>  OTTOMAN = OTT + OMAN
>
>  *Row 3:*
>  PIONEER = PI + ONE + ER (Queen Elizabeth II)
>  SEVENTH = VEN in SETH Rogen
>  SON = Periodic Table symbols for Sulfur, Oxygen and Nitrogen in trail order
>  SUFFOLK = [SU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(kana)) + F + [FOLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newport_Folk_Festival)

Next, group the words to form some meaningful clues that can have single-word answers...

> ...all of which have 3 letters:
>
>  SUFFOLK COUNTY HARBOR = [SAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sag_Harbor,_New_York)
>  OTTOMAN MILITARY OFFICER = [AGA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aga)
>  JACOB'S SEVENTH SON = [GAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gad_(son_of_Jacob))
>  COMPUTING PIONEER LOVELACE = [ADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace)

Finally, assemble the solution by...

> ...overlapping the four answers by a single letter at a time: SAG+AGA+GAD+ADA. This forms **[SAGADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagada)**, a municipality in the Philippines famed for its hanging coffins (traditional burial customs).

Comment: ha, seems like everybody took about the same amount of time to work through this one! nice work

Comment: Wouldn't it also be helpful to note that OP made a reference to burial customs in the title? IMO it would probably be a good thing to include.

Comment: Well done all. Was anyone else looking at the wrong part of the world for because they didn't pay enough attention to the third rebus?

Comment: @juicifer Indeed, well done! I think it took me longest to identify the hiragana... I think your wordplay for #8 is more explicitly correct.

Comment: @CrSb0001 (See the parentheses in the last section of my write-up - it's a direct quote from the puzzle's flavour text, which is itself what Jafe is referencing in the title...)

Comment: @DanielS Yes indeed. And for a looong time I thought I was looking at Somalia in #8...

Comment: @Stiv Oh my bad - I guess I didn't catch that at first :)

Comment: @Stiv I thought the same thing you did for #8 at first but was wondering why it was backwards! it felt like sloppy cluing until I realized it could work both ways lol

Answer (score 11):

Rebus answers:

> 1: Colorado's postal code is CO, followed by Vladimir PUTIN between MG gives **COMPUTING**
>  2: cos y divided by sin y equals COT Y, and with the UN in the middle, we get **COUNTY**
>  3: December 7, 1941 was the date of the attack on PEARL HARBOR, so leaving behind the PEARL, we're left with just **HARBOR**
>  4: this is just a bottle of **JACOB'S** Creek vintage chardonnay
>  5: 0 in tennis is called LOVE, a cubic decimeter is equivalent to a liter, which has symbol L, and the card is the ACE of spades, giving us **LOVELACE**
>  6: the Virgin MARY containing the letters ILIT gives **MILITARY**
>  7: the switch is OFF, and taking the R from Condoleezza RICE and moving it to the end, we get ICER, making **OFFICER**
>  8: the nation of OMAN containing the letters TTO gives **OTTOMAN**
>  9: we have PI, ONE, and a portrait of Queen Elizabeth, also known by her monogram, ER, giving **PIONEER**
>  10: SETH Rogan containing the letters VEN gives **SEVENTH**
>  11: elements 16, 8, and 7 are S, O and N, respectively, so we get **SON**
>  12: the glyph on top is a combination of the hiragana syllable SU and the letter F, while at the bottom we have the Newport FOLK festival. Putting these all together, we get **SUFFOLK**

Now, let's try to organize these into groups:

> a SUFFOLK COUNTY HARBOR is **[SAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sag_Harbor,_New_York)**
>  one rank of an OTTOMAN MILITARY OFFICER was **[AGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agha_(title))**
>  JACOB'S SEVENTH SON was **[GAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gad_(son_of_Jacob))**
>  LOVELACE COMPUTING PIONEER refers to **[ADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace)**

Combining all of these, we get

> **[SAGADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagada)**, a Filipino town noted for its custom of hanging coffins!